# update from another table with 2 primary keys

Tags: sql-update, composite-primary-key

i have two table T1 & T2 with same columns (service, desti,...)
composite primary key on T1 (service, desti)
I want to update t1 as data  in t2.

Plz advise,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're asking:

```
update t1 set col1 = t2.col1, col2 = t2.col2, etc
from t2
where t1.service = t2.service and t1.desti = t2.desti
```